# SpringBoot - J2EE Bad Practices: Leftover Debug Code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I fix the error `J2EE Bad Practices: Leftover Debug Code`? It is pointing to `public  static void main`. How can I avoid the error? I'm about to test everything without the main method and don't know if everything works without the main method.

```
"J2EE Bad Practices: Leftover Debug Code" => 3 Issues
​demo-api/src/main/java/com/apiDemo/ApiApplication.java:23 (Structural)
​demo-web/src/main/java/com/webDemo/WebApplication.java:22 (Structural)
​demo-web/src/main/java/demo/selenium/IBanTest.java:20 (Structural)
```

code:

```
package demo.selenium;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;



public class IBanTest {
    public  static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("iBan Selenium Testing");
        setup();
        IBanUpdateTest();
        IBanDeleteTest();
        IBanCreateTest();
        teardown();
    }
```

Similarly ApiApplication.java  has this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
}
```

And WebApplication.java has this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
}
```

Update:

I tested by removing the main methods from `ApiApplication.java` and `WebApplication.java` and the application is still working when packing from parent project. But doesn't work directly from child maven project. The errors disappeared after removing though.

I could remove IBanTest main method since the class file can't be used without the main method.

But it would be nice to include the main class and get rid of the errors somehow. Any suggestion would be nice.

Comment: It seem odd when i first read IBanTest class, IBanTest seem the test class, but it don't use @Test annotation and use main(...) instead ... Furthermore, System.out.println often use for debug purpose that's why few tool can warn about it.

Comment: what about the other java files? it doesn't have a System.out.println

Comment: I am not sure because i can't see the full code of 2 class. But you can try to change IBanTest and check if number errors is reduced.